# What is the windows user templates folder for?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, user-profiles

On Windows 7 Professional, my `C:\Users\<my-username>` folder contains a folder called "Templates" (i.e., `C:\Users\<my-username>\Templates`).

However, I've accidentally deleted this folder (permanently, it's not even in the recycle bin)!

What is the damage? What is this folder even used for anyway? (It was created when I made my Windows profile)

Comment: This is a non-default Windows folder, in other words, software installed on your at created the folder.  Without knowing the contents of the folder it’s impossible to explain the impact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was created by some software you installed on your computer. It is not a folder that Windows creates and uses by default.

To answer your question you will need to run applications on your computer to see if one notes it is missing this folder and its contents, or if the folder and its contents are recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook ad templates are pre made and free editable graphics that are used to run social media ads and business ads. Usually, facebook ads templates are in form of short videos and in form of pictures. When these graphics are edited, they will make your brand unique and suit your business.

Fb ads templates provide you to easy and free editable ads to create high quality ads for your business and company. these business ads will help you to promote your business, campaign or collection of products.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?